# QMacCocoaViewContainer doesn't show

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, qt

I built an official example qmaccocoaviewcontainer provided by Qt from QtCreator and I see nothing, but an empty window. MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5.
QMacCocoaViewContainer simply doesn't show up.

Here is the code:

```
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QMacCocoaViewContainer>

class WindowWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    WindowWidget()
    {
        QMacCocoaViewContainer *cocoaViewContainer = new QMacCocoaViewContainer(0, this);
        cocoaViewContainer->move(100, 100);
        cocoaViewContainer->resize(300, 300);
        NSTextView *text = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame : NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 300)];
        [text setString:@"the string"];
        cocoaViewContainer->setCocoaView(text);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    WindowWidget widget;
    widget.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: And your *specific* question is, what?

Comment: The question is why it doesn't show up. I didn't modify an example and it doesn't work

Comment: Have you *considered* that just *maybe* the example doesn't work? Sounds like time to break out the debugger.

Comment: Yes. That's what I thought

Comment: Which Qt version are you using? I've been facing somewhat similar behaviour with  Qt 5.10.x and Qt 5.11.x whereas Qt 5.9.6 works just fine with the same code.

Comment: I am using 5.11. Do you have any workground how to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately best I've managed do is stick with Qt 5.9.6 - if that version works better for you too. However there are a few QMacCocoaViewContainer related issues on Qt issues tracker for 5.9.x versions too..